# Mechanism for Synthesis of Tetranitromethane from Acetic Anhydride and Fuming Nitric Acid

Tags: organic-chemistry

In my undergraduate Mechanisms-class the formation of tetranitromethane from acetic Anhydride with fuming $\ce{HNO3}$ was listed as optional knowledge in a chapter about the reactions of enols, enamines, etc. I can't find it in my notes or in the recommended literature, neither can I find information on molbase, and the two papers I can find, the original 1910 synthesis and [This](http://orgsyn.org/Content/pdfs/procedures/CV3P0803.pdf), are not mentioning any reaction mechanism.

I guess it somehow decomposes at the stage when the acetic anhydride is tri-substituted on one side, and somewhere there is a trinitromethane-anion involved which forms the product with $\ce{NO2+}$?

Comment: Yeah, probably something like that.

Answer (score 3):

The [Organic Synthesis](http://orgsyn.org/Content/pdfs/procedures/CV3P0803.pdf) preparation you cited for the preparation of tetranitromethane has some clues that are useful in providing a viable mechanism. Upon slowly adding acetic anhydride (Ac<sub>2</sub>O) to anhydrous HNO<sub>3</sub> with cooling an exotherm is produced. The reaction mixture is allowed to sit at room temperature for 7 days. Assuming that they investigators did not go on vacation for a week, I presume that the formation of tetranitromethane (TNM) is slow and that the exotherm is due to the formation of the mixed anhydride **2**. [The nitronium cation is also a possible electrophile as well as the mixed anhydride **2**.] The enol of acetic anhydride can undergo substitution to afford species **3** and then repetitively on to the trinitro mixed anhydride **4**. Anhydride exchange with acetic acid (or nitric acid) affords trinitroacetic acid **5** which decarboxylates to enol **6** (*aci*-form). Tautomerization of **6** can form trinitromethane. Footnote 3 in the Organic Synthesis link mentions that trinitromethane **7** can be converted to tetranitromethane **8** with HNO<sub>3</sub>. The transformation of **6** to **8** does not preclude nitration via mixed anhydride **2**.   
[image]